# code works on one computer and not on another one

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
private void CreateDBFFile()
    {


        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;




        using (OleDbConnection dbconnection = new OleDbConnection(connection))
        using (OleDbCommand command = dbconnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            dbconnection.Open();

            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Test (Id Integer, Changed Double, Name Text)";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }



    }
```

The connection string is like this:

```
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="conn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\temp; Extended Properties=dBase IV" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"  />

</connectionStrings>
```

The above code works on my home computer, but not on my work computer. I don't know what file on my work computer went corrupt that above code terminates when I try to open the connection.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the same version of the database installed? Does your comapny lock ports? Is your company network firewalled?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Your `Data Source` is wrong.

Comment: this is  the issue, I didn't get any error. It just got terminated at dbconnection.open() without throwing any error.I am creating a new file so datasource is correct. I just have  to specify the path.Like I said, the code works on my home computer not on my work computer

Comment: The datasource should be a file name.  You said you are creating a new file.  What application is creating the new file?  Is it a Microsoft Office Product?  The Jet engine was used with 2003 Office and older.  2007 and later are now using the ACE instead.  So the reason it work on one PC and not the other is the new file was created under a different version of the application.  The version number of the application generating the file is store in the new file.  Make sure when you create the new file it is saved as a version that is compatible with JET.

Comment: I pointed the build of the application to X86 rather than X64,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is being caused by the processo architecture (x86 or x64), and the ODBC driver installed on Windows.

You are using the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider, so if your application is set to `Any CPU` on Visual Studio, and you run it on a `x86` computer, your application will look for the 32-bit version of the ODBC driver, and analogously if you run on a `x64` computer, your application will look for the 64-bit version of the ODBC driver.

It's a common problem of ODBC drivers and the `x86` / `x64` versions of Windows.

If you're sure the both computers have the 32-bit version of the ODBC driver, you can just "force" your application to run in 32-bit mode, usign:

> Right click on the Main project > Properties > Build > Plataform
>   target = x86

Even if your application are `x86` it will runs both on `x86` and `x64` versions of Windows.